# What would the 1st recursive call for this function look like?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
int Fun(int m, int n)
{

    if(n==0)
  {

    return n + 2;

  }

    return Fun(n-1, m-1) + Fun(m-1,n-1) + 1;

}
```

I'm completely lost as to what the 1st case would visually look like for this function. I don't understand why the function has two parameters and why we only return 1 parameter at the end with our base case. What would be the process to work this out? Any input you want to use to explain to me is fine I was trying (3,3). Although, now that I'm thinking about it how would this function look like if one of the inputs was smaller than the other like (3,2) or (2,3)?

Comment: What do you mean by *"what the 1st case would visually look like for this function"*? What is the "1st case"? And how do you want to visualize it?

Comment: I am afraid I fail to understand your question. For 3, 3 as starting input, you have these calls: Fun(2, 2) + Fun(2, 2) + 1, which keeps going down until you reach Fun(0, 0), which then returns 2.

Comment: Regarding the return, using an argument to calculate another value to return is quite common. Not all arguments have to be part of the calculations, they can be used for other things. On a related note, because the "base" case happens when `n == 0`, the statement `return n + 2;` is equivalent to `return 2;`. Does that make more sense to you?

Comment: The Great Secret of recursive functions is that they work exactly like non-recursive functions. Would you understand it if the last line read `Fun2(n-1, m-1) + Fun3(m-1,n-1) + 1;`, and you knew that `Fun2` and `Fun3` returned `int`s, even if you didn't know exactly what they did?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `return n + 2;` simplifies to `return 2;`.

The function takes two arguments (parameters) and returns a single value. That's like the operation of adding two numbers that you were taught in your first year at school.

Whether or not `Fun(n - 1, m - 1)` is called before `Fun(m - 1, n - 1)` is not specified by the C++ standard. So I can't tell you what the first recursive call will look like. This gives compilers more freedom in making optimisation choices. Of course the order in which the functions are called has no effect on the eventual result.

The best way of analysing what happens in your particular case is to use a line by line debugger.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about recursive functions - they work exactly like non-recursive functions.

`Fun(3,3)` does this:

```
if(3==0)
{
    return 3 + 2;
}
return Fun(2, 2) + Fun(2, 2) + 1;
```

It needs the value of `Fun(2,2)`, which does this:

```
if(2==0)
{
    return 2 + 2;
}
return Fun(1, 1) + Fun(1, 1) + 1;
```

And that needs `Fun(1,1)`, which does

```
if(1==0)
{
    return 1 + 2;
}
return Fun(0, 0) + Fun(0, 0) + 1;
```

and `Fun(0,0)` does

```
if(0==0)
{
    return 0 + 2;
}
return Fun(-1, -1) + Fun(-1, -1) + 1;
```

which returns 2 since the condition is true.

So, `Fun(1, 1)` will do

```
return 2 + 2 + 1;
```

which is 5, and `Fun(2,2)` will do

```
return 5 + 5 + 1;
```

which is 11, and `Fun(3,3)` will do

```
return 11 + 11 + 1;
```

which is 23.

I'm sure you can work through other examples on your own.